# Is there a name for the final section of a letter?

Tags: terminology, letter-writing

When writing a letter it typically starts out "Dear..." and then has the content, then before you sign it you might have a formal or informal (depending on who you're writing to) sign off, for example:

> blah blah blah letter content blah blah.
>
> Kind regards/Many thanks/Best wishes/Cheers!/etc

Does this final closing portion of your letter have a name?

For comparison, the middle portion of the letter is the body and the opener could be described as a greeting or, more accurately, the salutation. but I don't think this last bit could be called a farewell as such.

So what should it be called?

Comment: As an aside, the middle portion of a letter is usually called the "body" of the letter. The opening is commonly called the "Salutation" though "Greeting" is also acceptable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have always heard the "Sincerely, Joe Smith" part of a letter called the **closing**.

(And the part you describe as the greeting ("Dear Mr. Blahblah") I'm used to calling the **salutation**.)

Comment: Yep, in fact, when searching Google, you would search for "How can I best 'close a letter'" Described as a closing here: http://www.wisegeek.com/what-should-i-include-in-a-personal-letter.htm Some ways you can close a letter: http://www.5steps2english.com/forums/salutation_and_closing_letter-t683.0.html

Comment: As one example of the usage in practice of those terms, Microsoft Word has had built-in styles with those names for years.

Comment: @OneProton one link is dead and the other doesn't make a reliable impression.

Answer (score 31):

It's called a *valediction* or a *complimentary close.* The opening phrase is called a *salutation.*

Comment: This. [+1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valediction).

Comment: valediction | ˌvaləˈdikSHən |
noun
the action of saying farewell

Answer (score 2):

I would describe it as a "valedictory"..."farewell words".

Comment: Or simply, a "farewell"?

Comment: Yeah, that works, too.

Answer (score 0):

Valediction would be correct although it is neither used as frequently nor as familiarly as the term, "salutation" (which describes the beginning greeting). I suppose we have E.B. White's "Charlotte" to thank for that.