# What meant Winston Churchill by 'consideration'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, valediction

I know that these olden [valedictions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11101/is-there-a-name-for-the-final-section-of-a-letter#comment18830_11115) are phatic expressions, but I still fancy knowing:

1. which definition of '[consideration](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/consideration)' fits? Does "consider" here mean (1.1) ["turn over in one's mind" or (1.2) "regard a certain way"](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/consider?s=t)? Or something else?
2. For what has the writer "high consideration"?

> [ [Source :](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_declaration_of_war_on_Japan) ] I have the honour to be, with high consideration,
>
> Sir,
>
> Your obedient servant,
>
> Winston S. Churchill<sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_declaration_of_war_on_Japan#cite_note-1)</sup>

More olden valedictions with 'consideration': ['with consideration'](https://founders.archives.gov/index.xqy?q=%22with+consideration%22&s=1111211111&sa=&r=1&sr=), ['with high consideration'](https://founders.archives.gov/index.xqy?q=%22with+high+consideration%22&s=1111211111&sa=&r=1&sr=).

Comment: While questions about older expressions are not necessarily off-topic, silly archaisms in titles don't do much for site respectability.

Comment: Your title is ungrammatical, take your pick: (1) What **did**  Churchill mean when he wrote: “ith high consideration”? (2) What **does** [Churchill's] "with high consideration" mean? (3) What **is** the meaning of "high consideration" used by Churchill?

Answer (score 1):

“With high consideration” is  a dated set phrase   often found in formal letters  as a form of salutation.

***Consideration:***

> 5. High regard; esteem.

(AHD)

Today we would more commonly use; *Your sincerely*

Consideration  here literally means esteem, respect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like he is referring to the manner in which one is regarded. "In high consideration," can be an expression meaning to be in high regard or highly respected. It looks as if that's what was intended here. In this case it is a respectful salutation common in the closing of a correspondence, indicating the writer's respect for the recipient.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please note that an answer containing supporting evidence is far better than one lacking any.